# How to transfer a file via bluetooth using Ymodem in iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I am tasked with updating a bluetooth device's firmware. I am using Swift and need some idea on how to accomplish this. Here are the instructions.

> Protocol: Ymodem. Handshake with unit, In Ymodem, the 1024 bytes is
>   changed to 256bytes, detailed algorithm refers to source code we
>   provide.

I have the .bin file and am able to download it to my app but I have no idea how to transfer it to the device after I make the bluetooth connection using Ymodem. I see very little on the web for Ymodem and iOS.

Comment: The first thing you need to check is if your device supports BLE. If it wants the transfer over a legacy Serial Port Profile then you won't be able to do it unless the device is MFi certified.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks, I have been able to connect via BLE. Is there a specific library I need to use for this?

Comment: CoreBluetooth is the framework for basic connectivity. Presumably the peripheral implements a virtual serial port over one or two characteristics. You will probably need to implement the Y Modem protoocol yourself. I can't imagine it is the sort of thing anyone would have done in Swift, but you could try searching I guess.